# benefices of big data on machine learning methodologies

Tags: predictive-models, large-data

I know that there are a number of predictive models (generized linear ones, trees, neural network, support vector machines, knn, Naive Bayes, ...) that have been proposed to perform various analytical tasks. Now I am striving to find appropriate references about their performance when the data becames "Big". In other words, how is their performance when the data becames really big. Does the training time increase more than linear? Is there any comparative benchmark between computational time and precision when the data becames high (for the various predictive models).

Comment: this may be better suited for the [data science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Comment: In English, the word "benefices" in [the sense I think you intend](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/benefice#English) would usually be regarded as archaic or obsolete -- are you after the word 'benefits"?